# Swagger UI model rendering issue in WSO2

Tags: wso2, swagger, swagger-ui

Swagger UI in a WSO2 application renders model schemas in the Model tab incorrectly. Currently it shows the HTML markup as is:

[image: Model view Bug]

It is supposed to look like this:

[image: Model window supposed to be]

I would really appreciate if someone can enlighten me what's wrong and how can I fix that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in WSO2 2.0.0 version and the fix is located here:
https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/pull/3271/files